# how to move field in purchase order to stock.picking, stock.move, and stock.quant?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created 4 custom fields in purchase.order, stock.picking, stock.move and stock.quant.

How to do when the purchase order is confirmed, the data from the field I created in purchase order is filled in stock.picking and stock.move?
and when stock.picking in approve the data also filled in?

i using odoo 10
thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: for field from to to PO to stock.picking have successfully used this source code:
@api.model
    def _prepare_picking(self):
        vals = super(InheritPoType, self)._prepare_picking()
        vals.update({
            'field_in_stock_picking': self.field_in_po,
        })
        return vals

but i can not do the same for to stock.move